# MySQL Fulltext search where category = something

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me crazy, I have searched everywhere and can not seem to find an example. I am doing a fulltext MySQL search like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE MATCH (
`title` , `description` , `location`
)
AGAINST (
'SEARCH TERM'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

that works fine but I have another column in my table "category" and would like to return results only from that category something like:

SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE MATCH (
`title` , `description` , `location`
)
AGAINST (
'fayetteville'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
WHERE `category` = 'SEARCH CATEGORY'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100

of course that second bit of code does not work, but how can I do this in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one WHERE clause. Change your second WHERE to AND.

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE MATCH ( `title` , `description` , `location` )
      AGAINST ( 'fayetteville' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
AND `category` = 'SEARCH CATEGORY'
ORDER BY `id`
DESC LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: Thanks! your a god. I hasn't been 5 minutes so I can't accept your answer. I will when it lets me.

Comment: Had exactly the same question. Thanks for this post.